# All Twitter Scrapers not working every scraper is giving error 403 Forbidden, even I can't fetch tweets using twitter API's

Tags: python-3.x, api, web-scraping, twitter

I am trying to scrape tweets for my project but no scrapers is working from this week, I remember last week i scrape lots of tweets but right now, none is working.

I am getting error 403 Forbidden on all scrapers even using twitter API, i can't fetch tweets.

Forbidden: 403 Forbidden
453 - You currently have Essential access which includes access to Twitter API v2 endpoints only. If you need access to this endpoint, you’ll need to apply for Elevated access via the Developer Portal. You can learn more here: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/getting-started/about-twitter-api#v2-access-leve

Comment: yep, it's because of new policy by twitter where they decided to prevent search functionality for anonymous users effectively blocking all scrappers